# Consultation for using 2 databases with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, cassandra, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I want to consult you

If I have a built-in Laravel project and want to add a messaging feature that will have big traffic, I thought that using a NoSQL database with MySQL database may be better for the MySQL database in many ways like:

1. Freeing up storage (as the data that will be stored in the MySQL is only the user's message)
2. Decreasing traffic on the MySQL database

So am I right?

Is this best practice?

And if so, What do you recommend a DB service?

I made a search about it (DynamoDB,Firebase,Cassandra) and read about their pros and cons and want to take advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not pretty clear. What kind of messages are you trying to implement? Is it about mailing or just notifications? Why would you need a DB to get involved in messaging? For app notifications, you have broadcasting and Laravel echo. For massive mailing, you would probably need 3rd party API. For push notifications, there are many services such as Firebase. But again, your goal is not clear at all

Comment: My goal is save messages for history backups

Comment: But as I said I am quite thinking of Big storage and database traffic, so I am thinking of creating another DB that holds messages operations

Comment: At first sight, I would tell you "use the same DB" because of DB integrity and queries performance. Assuming your messages table has a FK to the owner and you need to fetch all messages from a specific user, you would need to fetch the user table from DB A and join messages from DB B. What about if you delete a user from DB A? All your messages from DB B will become orphans. I think it depends mostly on your business logic, but some packages like spatie/laravel-activitylog keep track of all the activity, which implies millions of records, in the same DB with no issues at all.